# iis server export bcd file in use

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8

I'm migrating the webserver to a different server. So I tried to export the IIS server into a server package. I've done this before and it worked like a charm every time. Today though this error message popped up. I used the default full export settings. Does anyone know why IIS tries to back-up the BCD?

**ERROR:** The file 'BCD' is in use.  The process cannot access c:\Boot\BCD because it is being used by another process.

[image]

Full res image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO8fY.png

Comment: I know what happened. One of the sites was a domain linkthrough telling via a 302 to route to our main domain. Because this was done through the url rewrite module someone set the www folder to C:/. That's why the package manager wanted to back-up the whole C:/ drive. 

I just wanted to thank @TheCleaner for his editing.

Sadly I can't answer my own question so could someone please set it to answered for me.

Comment: You can answer your own question.  Post it as the answer and then you'll be able to accept it later.  That's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: When I tried that it said I needed more than 10 points to do so. Or I need to wait for a couple of hours.

Comment: Ah...true: http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/new-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what happened. One of the sites was a domain linkthrough telling via a 302 to route to our main domain. Because this was done through the url rewrite module someone set the www folder to C:/. That's why the package manager wanted to back-up the whole C:/ drive.